# What is the use of ".@ " in groovy?

Tags: groovy

What is the use of `.@` in groovy? Can anyone explain me with a code snippet?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's the Java Field operator ([according to the documentation](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Operators#Operators-Javafield%28.@%29))

There are examples in the documentation.

It is also used for [accessing attributes when you are parsing XML](http://groovy.329449.n5.nabble.com/Using-the-dot-at-operator-to-fetch-a-XML-attribute-td372529.html) (again, there's an example if you follow that link).

Comment: As the documentation suggest that we should not use it unless it needed, can you specify a simple example of where it can be very handy ?

Comment: No not exactly, but anything where it is useful

Answer (score 9):

Have you seen the official [documentation](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Operators#Operators-Javafield(.@))? It contains nice code samples.

Essentially, when you use normal `.` operator, you access fields indirectly, using implicitly generated getters/setters. However, `.@` allows you to access the field directly, skipping getter/setter.

This can be useful when you want to avoid some additional logic implemented in getter/setter and change the field directly. Violates tons of OOP principles, but the authors of Groovy found this construct to be useful.